# Jetty SslConnectionFactory nextProtocol

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I am looking at some example code for configuring Jetty to use https.

In the example it uses SslContextFactory, and passes "h2" as its second argument.

```
SslConnectionFactory ssl = new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "h2");
```

I was curious what this string is. When I went to look at **[the docs](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.24.v20191120/org/eclipse/jetty/server/SslConnectionFactory.html#%3Cinit%3E(org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory,java.lang.String))**, it says absolutely nothing about it what it is.

So what is this nextProtocol parameter?

Comment: See `ConnectionFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

"Next Protocol" is how protocols are resolved during the initial connection.

The ConnectionFactory concepts controls all of this.

Typically this is used for HTTP/2 where in a TLS/1.2+ environment with ALPN in the mix, but people do use it for other things.  If you look at the history of ALPN you'll no doubt find the older (now deprecated) extension called NPN which was called "Next Protocol Negotiation".

Common Examples:

- a single port that serves both plaintext HTTP and encrypted HTTPS.
- a single port that serves PROXY 4, PROXY 5, HTTP/1.x, and HTTP/2.x.
- a single port that can handle HTTP/1.1, and HTTP/2, and other protocols (like any of the myriad RPC protocols).